# JSON TREE MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

I want to create a Json tree from 3 collection taked from a MongoDB.

For example :

[image]

Each area can be connected to an other area, the spaces can be connected to an area and to another space, and finally the dash are connected to the spaces.

Which way is recommended for storing trees? And how to recover them properly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [mongo-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-tree)  , this module provides CRUD operation methods for inserting, updating, and removing of entire tree structures to a MongoDB collection.